# What can cause jquery.data() disappearing?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with jQuery element.data() resetting mysteriously. I've checked that the data is stored ok to the element on a click event.

[Some simple tests to recreate the problem (with no success) here.](http://jsfiddle.net/marqs/Gb8CS/3/)

What happens after the data-storing is a series of actions, changing id:s for the data-fields, form submit, handling of the response, some rendering etc... In short, enough things that it's slow to find the problem. I've checked the $.cache-object which doesn't have the data I stored. The .removeData's in the code all target the submit-button in the form where I edit the input-fields.

```
$element.removeData('attribute');
```

Any ideas what things can cause the data to reset?

jQuery.data source [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js)

Comment: Could it be that the submit of your form triggers a reload of the page (and therefore a loss of all data stored in $.data)?

Comment: Are you removing that element from the DOM at some point and reinserting it later in your code?

Comment: Try installing firebug and firequery in firefox, then you can see what data is on an element. Watch that as you step through your code and see when the data disapears.

Comment: The submit is an ajax submit, so no reload. I'm not removing the input so that shouldn't be the issue either.

Comment: I have to test this on a better time. I did some testing with firequery, but no big revelation yet. This seems like a complicated issue for me to debug, so I just implemented a cache-system inside the JS object. It would have been a simpler solution to get it done with .data(), and I plan to test this to better understand .data().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed your html templates?

I recently dealt with the same problem where data was disappearing on a click event. I had re-templated my html and was attaching the data on a parent node, but the click event was firing on a child node.

```
<div> <!-- The data was attached here -->
  <div class="clickable"> <!-- click events were firing here -->


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This problem was a while back, but I'm guessing it was probably something similar. Either re-writing the element or using a wrong node..

Answer (score 1):

Jquery data also gets removed from an element when the element gets removed from the DOM. You can still access the deleted element inside a mutation observer, but the Jquery data on it is gone.

Comment: That was it for me. The node was getting cut from one parent and pasted into another. I right clicked the node in chrome dev tools, and "add breakpoint" -> "node removal" and found the exact point where all the data was getting removed. Thanks @Nick

Answer (score 0):

Is this asp.net by any chance?  I know that ajax calls made using asp.net ajax are non-destructive post-backs, but they DO hose up client side scripting code (javascript).  Try this:

Create a text box html input (hidden is fine) and store the data value in there also.  Check the value of that input after the ajax call to make sure the input value is still set.

If you still have the value, but are missing js updates (including any js variables), then that ajax call is doing a post-back that isn't destroying form content but is destroying javascript code.

Comment: It's not .net, no framework in use, just jQuery, openlayers and JSON APIs.

Comment: There shouldn't be any destruction of JS, unless something leaks out from OL or the custom map library. But they don't do any jQuery data manipulation, or those parts of DOM that have the data.